# automatic login to wordpress dashboard from another site

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, automation

I want to log in automatically to WP admin/dashboard from another site without going thru the login process.. I've tried the following but with no luck:

```
<?php

$username="admin";
$password="mypasw";
$url="http://example.com/";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&testcookie=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "wp-login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
exit;


?>
```

It's kind of like only showing me the dashboard page but I'm not really logged in since clicking on any buttons on the admin page is only redirecting to same page which is the site page.. :(

Comment: So what is the problem now? What is the error showing right now

Comment: What is the use of cookie.txt file?

Comment: @Jerin sorry about the cookie.txt.. it's not included.. the problem now is that it only shows the dashboard page but the all the functions are not working.. like if i click on users, it's directed to the site, not on the list of users.. so it's as if it's not logged in properly but i'm only seeing a screenshot of the dashboard it seems

Comment: Do you have FTP access of the website you are trying to login?

Comment: Ok, see my answer I posted below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have access to the files of the website where you trying to login. You could add a auto login php script and $_POST the username and password to this script, example:

```
if ($_POST) {

    $errors = array();

    $username = esc_sql($_REQUEST['username']);
    $password = esc_sql($_REQUEST['password']);
    $remember = esc_sql($_REQUEST['rememberme']);
    $remember = ($remember) ? "true" : "false";

    $login_data = array();
    $login_data['user_login'] = $username;
    $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
    $login_data['remember'] = $remember;
    $user_verify = wp_signon($login_data, true);

    if (is_wp_error($user_verify)) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!';
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->ID);
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit;
    }

}
```

Wordpress codex references:

- Login function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon
- Set cookie for admin login http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie
- Get the admin page url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** $wpdb->escape is deprecated since Wordpress version 3.6, use wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql() instead! I've changed the code to use esc_sql().

- esc_sql(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql

Comment: yes.. this helps.. i just edited some like $wpdb->escape.. thanks!

Comment: How to login in to wordpress admin from ASP.net website?

Answer (score 0):

Try This complete code it working 100%
First Website : http://firstwebsite.com and
Second Website : http://secondwebsite.com

Now, first of all create a link on your first website, on which we want to click to go to our second website as a logged in user. So, in your first website create a link at your desired place as mentioned below :

```
<?php   global $current_user;
$second_website_url = 'http://secondwebsite.com'; // put your second website url
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;
$user_login = $current_user->user_login;
if($user_email != ''){

$email_encoded = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($user_email), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
$user_login_encoded = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($user_login), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
echo '<a href="'.$second_website_url.'/sso.php? 
key='.$email_encoded.'&detail='.$user_login_encoded.'" target="_blank">Link to 
second website</a>';
}?>
```

Now, open our second website and create a new php file and name it as “sso.php”. Place this file at your root installation and just copy paste the below mentioned code in this file :

```
<?php

require_once( 'wp-load.php' ); //put correct absolute path for this file


global $wpdb;

if(isset($_GET['key']) && !empty($_GET['key'])){

$email_decoded = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['key'], '-_', '+/'));   
$username_decoded = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['detail'], '-_', '+/')); 

$received_email = sanitize_text_field($email_decoded);
$received_username = sanitize_text_field($username_decoded);


if( email_exists( $received_email )) {

        //get the user id for the user record exists for received email from database 
        $user_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->users." WHERE user_email = %s", $received_email ) );

        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id); //login the previously exist user

        wp_redirect(site_url()); // put the url where you want to redirect user after logged in

}else {

        //register those user whose mail id does not exists in database 

        if(username_exists( $received_username )){

            //if username coming from first site exists in our database for any other user,
            //then the email id will be set as username
            $userdata = array(
            'user_login'  =>  $received_email,
            'user_email'  =>  $received_email, 
            'user_pass'   =>  $received_username,   // password will be username always
            'first_name'  =>  $received_username,  // first name will be username
            'role'        =>  'subscriber'     //register the user with subscriber role only
        );

        }else {

            $userdata = array(
            'user_login'  =>  $received_username,
            'user_email'  =>  $received_email, 
            'user_pass'   =>  $received_username,   // password will be username always
            'first_name'  =>  $received_username,  // first name will be username
            'role'        =>  'subscriber'     //register the user with subscriber role only
        );

        }


        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ; // adding user to the database

        //On success
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
             
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id); //login that newly created user
            wp_redirect(site_url()); // put the url where you want to redirect user after logged in

        }else{

            echo "There may be a mismatch of email/username with the existing record.
                  Check the users with your current email/username or try with any other account.";die;
        }


}

 die;

 } ?>
```