# Wordpress Login from another site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to login on wordpress site from another site using below code.

```
require_once('wordpress/wp-load.php');

function login_wordpress($username, $password) {
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login']    = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        return $user->get_error_message();
       //die();
   }
    else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
        return $user->ID . ' ' . $username;
    }
}
```

When I print `$user` variable then I got all user Information but I am unable to create cookies using `wp_set_auth_cookie` function and I dont login on wordpress site.

Anyone can help me on this issue.

I got this idea from [automatic login to wordpress dashboard from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807293/automatic-login-to-wordpress-dashboard-from-another-site)

**NOTE:-** I have checked that wp_set_auth_cookie working with www url. In wordpress database siteurl is saved with www and I am running my another site without www. Is It possible to create cookies for with or without www? Is any way to use wp_set_auth_cookie with or without www..?

Comment: Did you find any solution? i am still confused

Comment: Hey this is working for me

Comment: Yeah working fine for me too. :)