# Wordpress inside iframe with automated login/logout

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs, iframe, authentication

I've a ReactJS/NodeJS application with GraphQL API and authentication behind JWT and wordpress to handle some services such as the native blog, ecommerce (woocommerce plugin) and forum (simple:press plugin).
This ReactJS application implements a login/register form creating 2 accounts on its internal database and wordpress at the same time.

To integrate Wordpress we're currently mixing wordpress REST APIs and iframe to integrate the forum and the ecommerce directly on ReactJS app for now.

I'm struggling now to find a solution to automatically login an account on Wordpress using the app login form. My goal is to allow the login via app and let the user to automatically be logged on Wordpress pages rendered by the iframe. The same for logout.

I've found a similar approach here: [automatic login to wordpress dashboard from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807293/automatic-login-to-wordpress-dashboard-from-another-site)

But i'm not sure it's the same issue.

Comment: _“But i'm not sure it's the same issue.”_ - looks at least similar enough that it should be able to get you started. Any specific questions/issues besides that?

Comment: I could try to create a REST Api on Wordpress with that php code suggested on related question. Then send an AJAX POST request from ReactJS app with username and password. Is it Wordpress able to create a cookie for its domain via an AJAX call?

Comment: Should be; whether that cookie gets accepted by the browser might depend on settings regarding 3rd-party cookies though.