# How to Connect session from a PHP Script and a wordpress website

Tags: php, database, wordpress, session, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a Php users to a WordPress website, but I do not want them to login to the wordpress website. I want them to connect the session of the PHP Project to that of the WordPress database so it would show their username on the WordPress project.

This is for a PHP Project I'm trying to connect the session to that of a wordpress page.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807293/automatic-login-to-wordpress-dashboard-from-another-site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [automatic login to wordpress dashboard from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807293/automatic-login-to-wordpress-dashboard-from-another-site)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I appreciate,